# How to limit internet traffic in some computers of my home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, home-networking, limited-access, dir-655

I'm sharing my home wireless network, using a DIR-655 Wireless Router with 3 other people (2 using windows machines and one use mac laptop, I also use a mac laptop). I need to know how can I limit internet traffic from their computers.

Reason: I pay for the internet, but I'm having to pay extra every month because I'm going over the bandwidth limit of my internet provider.

Comment: do you want to limit as in allow some usage, or deny completely ?

Comment: Do you want to limit the bandwidth for the users, or do you want to set quotas? The latter might be more helpful to avoid exceeding your paid volume.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes routers have a QoS (Quality of Service) options that might be helpful in this situation.  Sorry for not being more specific, but hopefully it might get you better results searching with that term or looking for QoS settings in your router configuration.

Comment: The DIR-655 has QoS and even has an online emulator for those without access to the router: http://support.dlink.com/Emulators/dir655/121/Traffic_Shaping.html

Comment: I already did, but the QoS option just prioritize connections but do not have any options for limiting connections. In my case priority of connections is not that relevant.

Answer (score 2):

use a router that is supported by **[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/dd-wrt/about.html)** (the D-Link DIR-655 is not supported)

```
* supports more than 200 different devices
* comprehensive functionality
* supports all current WLAN standards (802.11a/b/g/n*)
* supports outdoor deployment*
* supports enhanced frequencies *
* VPN integration
* supports various Hotspot systems
* bandwidth management
* multilingual user interface
```

for the Windows computers, you may use **[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)**, a nice software solution