# How to set limit on others' traffic in a home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, network-traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to limit internet traffic in some computers of my home network?](https://superuser.com/questions/44190/how-to-limit-internet-traffic-in-some-computers-of-my-home-network)

Here's the problem: I have Internet account with limit of 3G per month.
there are some computers in my home network which use the Internet account through a wireless router.
Is there a way to set a limit on the other users' traffic  in the network by mac address or IP address ?
Is there a tool for it?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the wireless router you use, you should probably look into running the DD-WRT router firmware, which supports throttling, bandwidth management, and other functions that you'll find useful for this, as well as being a very highly regarding alternative firmware for a very wide variety of routers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a firmware replacement called [Gargoyle](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/) available for several common home routers that will let you set quota's and throttling. There are probably a number of others that will allow this as well.